# How to deal with a pointer to an Objective-C object in a C++ app

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa

I have a C++ application that makes use of a third-party library, written in C/C++. The library contains a function that returns a pointer to a NSWindow, namely an Objective-C element from the Cocoa Framework.

At some point of my code I call that function, but before proceeding I have to do a very small operation on that NSWindow (say for example change a flag or something). In other words, I have to call an Objective-C method of an Objective-C object in a C++ context. What is in your opinion the best/correct way to do that?

Comment: Your question lacks detail. Try typing *Objective-C++* into your favourite search engine and you'll find plenty to read.

Comment: Can you use C++11? Could you use Objective-C++ in your project (it may be easy to do).

Comment: @JBL sure I can, the app is written in C++11 style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Objective-C++ file (.mm) in which you just use a block like you'd use a lambda:

```
//In an .mm file
auto changeFlag = ^(/* your params */ ) {
    [yourObjCObject yourObjCMethod];
};
```

You can then pass that callback to a c++ context as an [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and call it there.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can make you file an Objective-C++ by changing its extension to .mm
   That way you can mix C++ and obj-c code in the single file.
2. If that approach is not correct for you, you can look at the low-level obj-c object message sending.
   All method call in obj-c are converted to low-level like

   id data = ...;

   objc_msgSend(data, sel_getUid("release")); // [data release];